# Update Entity Framework 6 Objetos desconectados Entidades 1:N (Uno a muchos)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estoy haciendo una aplicación y uso Entity Framework 6 para acceder a SQL Server.

Tengo el siguiente caso, donde quiero actualizar el valor de dos entidades:

`Socio` -> `SocioDireccion`   Un socio puede tener muchas direcciones.

Primero llamo a este método para leer un socio:

```
public Socio Leer(int id)
{
    Socio resultado = null;

    using (var context = new BDConectaClubContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        //Usando Include linq lambda

        resultado = context.Socio
            .Include(s => s.CuentaBancaria)
            .Include(s=> s.Direcciones)
            .Include(s=>s.EMails)
            .Include(s=>s.Grupos)
            .Include(s=>s.Vocalias)
            .Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault<Socio>();
    }


    return resultado;

}
```

En la base de datos, el Socio leído tiene una sola dirección. 
Le añado dos direcciones más, fuera del contexto, ya que son entidades desconectadas, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
Socio.
----------------
Id
38 (Modificación)


SocioDireccion
---------------
Id    Socio_Id
1     38 (Modificación)
0     38 (Alta)
0     38 (Alta)
```

Llamo al siguiente método que me sirve para añadir o modificar un socio:

```
public bool Guardar(Socio socio)
{
    int r; 
    using (var ctx = new BDConectaClubContext())
    {

        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // Alta funciona correctamente
        if (socio.Id == 0)
        {
            ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Added;
            foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
            {
                ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            r = ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            //Aquí se produce el error
            ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;             


            foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
            {
                if (d.Id == 0)
                    ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
                else
                    ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            r = ctx.SaveChanges();
        }


        return r > 0;
    }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta esta línea

```
ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

... se produce el siguiente error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'RMG.ConectaClub.Modelos.SocioDireccion' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Lo más curioso es que si solo añado una dirección nueva a `SocioDireccion` no se produce el error y funciona correctamente la modificación:

```
Socio
-------
Id
38 (Modificación)


SocioDireccion
---------------------
Id Socio_Id
1 38 (Modificación)
0 38 (Alta)
```

Con sola una dirección nueva no se produce el error. Si hay más de una, sí se produce el error.

He hecho un ejemplo sencillo para que veáis cómo añado la información a las entidades:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Crear un nuevo socio llamada Pepe con una direccion a
    Socio s = new Socio();
    s.Nombre = "Pepe";

    SocioDireccion direccion = new SocioDireccion();
    direccion.Direccion = "calle a";
    direccion.Socio = s;

    s.Direcciones.Add(direccion);

    new FachadaSocio().Guardar(s);


    //Leer el socio Pepe y crear dos direcciones a y b
    Socio nuevoSocio = new FachadaSocio().Leer(s.Id);

    SocioDireccion dir;
    dir = new SocioDireccion();
    dir.Direccion = "calle b";
    dir.Socio = nuevoSocio;

    nuevoSocio.Direcciones.Add(dir);

    dir = new SocioDireccion();
    dir.Direccion = "calle c";
    dir.Socio = nuevoSocio;
    nuevoSocio.Direcciones.Add(dir);

    // El socio Pepe tiene 3 direcciones a,b,c
    new FachadaSocio().Guardar(nuevoSocio);

}
```

Añado más información:

El error puede estar relacionado con esto que he detectado. ¿Me podríais decir si es un funcionamiento correcto?

Me recorro la lista de direcciones. Cuando una dirección tiene el `Id=0`, le cambio el estado a `Added`. Pero se puede observar, al hacer una inspección, que me ha añadido todo el resto de entidades de Direcciones y además la entidad Socio.

```
foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
{                        
    estadoDireccion = ctx.Entry(d).State;

    if (d.Id == 0)
        // Al ejecutar esta instrucción añade el resto de Direcciones y la entidad Socio.
        ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added; 
    else
        ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

`ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;` me agrega al contexto toda la lista de direcciones y además agrega al contexto el Socio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actúa exactamente igual que si estuviera añadiendo una entidad padre que añade todas las hijas con el estado añadido.

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: ¿Cómo añades la dirección? Tiene pinta de que está generando conflicto porque añades todas con id = 0, y está entendiendo que es un update para estas direcciones en lugar de un insert. Quizá te funcionaría modificando el estado de las direcciones antes de modificar el estado del socio.

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo para que veas cómo añado la información en las entidades. Gracias por tu aportación

Answer (score 1):

El problema con:

```
ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

... es que no solo cambia el `State` de `socio` a `Modified`, sino que también recorre todas las direcciones y si encuentra alguna que esté `Detached`, les cambia el `State` a `Unchanged` automáticamente.

Ahora bien, `Unchanged` representa una entidad que ya existe en la base de datos. Pero en el caso que te da error, la verdad es que tienes 2 direcciones que aun no existen en la base de datos, de modo que ponerle el state `Unchanged` en realidad es una mentira y no es correcto.

Con una sola dirección nueva, la mentira pasa desapercibida, y de todas maneras luego corriges el `State` a `Added` o `Modified` y no pasa nada.

Pero cuando tienes por lo menos 2 direcciones nuevas, ahora la mentira se siente, porque EF nota 2 entidades que *supuestamente* ya existen en la base de datos, pero que comparten la misma clave primaria (`Id = 0`), y eso no le gusta, de modo que te lanza el error.

La solución es sencilla: cambia el `State` de las direcciones **antes** de cambiar el `State` de `socio` a `Modified`. De esta forma, para cuando ejecutas la sentencia problemática, ya las direcciones no estarán en el `State = Detached`, y EF no intentará ponerles el `State` a `Unchanged`, lo que sería incorrecto.

**Código:**

```
else
{
    foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
    {
        if (d.Id == 0)
            ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
        else
            ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // Mueve esta sentencia después de las direcciones.
    ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;             

    r = ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edición**

Lo siento que aun tengas el problema a pesar de reordenar las sentencias para modificar el `State` de las direcciones antes de la del socio. Parece que subestimé la forma como EF modifica los `State` de forma automática siguiendo los *navigation properties*.

Creo que lo que está pasando es lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutas la sentencia siguiente: `ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;`
2. EF nota que la dirección está relacionada a la instancia `socio` que aun está `Detached`, así que la cambia a `Unchanged`.
3. Partiendo de la instancia `socio`, EF encuentra las demás direcciones y nota que están a `Detached`, así que trata de cambiarlas a `Unchanged` antes que tengas la oportunidad de cambiarles el `State` tu mismo a `Modified`, lo que causa el error, porque tienes mas de una dirección con `Id = 0`.

En fin, aunque no se entienda mi explicación del todo, te propongo una modificación, que ahora sí, creo que va a resolver el problema.

Creo que aunque estés en el modo *update*, deberías cambiar el `State` de `socio` a `Added`. Esto tiene el efecto (como ya notastes) de cambiar el `State` de todas las direccione a `Added`, cuyo `State` no causa problemas con `Id = 0`.

La etapa siguiente es de modificar el `State` de las direcciones a `Added` o `Modified` como lo haces ya.

Y finalmente, la etapa final: le cambias el `State` a la instancia `socio` otra vez, pero esta vez a `Modified`.

**Código:**

```
else
{
    // 1. Asigna el state "Added" temporalmente para eliminar el error.
    ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Added;             

    // 2. Asigna los states a tus direcciones normalmente.
    foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
    {
        if (d.Id == 0)
            ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
        else
            ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // 3. Ahora sí le cambias el state a "Modified" sin problemas.
    ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;             

    r = ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Nota final**

En realidad, el hecho que el código se complique tanto es señal de que el diseño no es el mejor. En realidad, EF no trabaja muy bien con entidades desconectadas, particularmente cuando hay varias entidades relacionadas.

De estar en tu lugar, pensaría seriamente en trabajar con entidades "conectadas" a un contexto que no se cierra hasta que terminas de trabajar con las entidades. Si lo intentas, verás que el código queda muy reducido y simplificado, y funciona de forma más intuitiva.

Basándome en el código existente que tienes, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de código usando entidades "contectas". Nota que el método `Guardar` desaparece completamente:

**Método `Leer`**:

```
public Socio Leer(int id, DbContext context)
{
        //Usando Include linq lambda
        return context.Socio
            .Include(s => s.CuentaBancaria)
            .Include(s=> s.Direcciones)
            .Include(s=>s.EMails)
            .Include(s=>s.Grupos)
            .Include(s=>s.Vocalias)
            .Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Event handler:**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Socio s;
    using (var ctx = new BDConectaClubContext())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        //Crear un nuevo socio llamada Pepe con una direccion a
        s = new Socio();
        s.Nombre = "Pepe";

        SocioDireccion direccion = new SocioDireccion();
        direccion.Direccion = "calle a";
        direccion.Socio = s;

        s.Direcciones.Add(direccion);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var ctx = new BDConectaClubContext())
    {
        //Leer el socio Pepe y crear dos direcciones a y b
        Socio nuevoSocio = new FachadaSocio().Leer(s.Id, ctx);

        SocioDireccion dir;
        dir = new SocioDireccion();
        dir.Direccion = "calle b";
        dir.Socio = nuevoSocio;

        nuevoSocio.Direcciones.Add(dir);

        dir = new SocioDireccion();
        dir.Direccion = "calle c";
        dir.Socio = nuevoSocio;
        nuevoSocio.Direcciones.Add(dir);

        // El socio Pepe tiene 3 direcciones a,b,c
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: He realizado lo que me dices, pero me salta el mismo error. La verdad es que me trae de cabeza y no consigo avanzar, algo estoy haciendo mal y no se lo que es. Gracias por tu aportación. ¿Se te ocurre alguna idea?

Comment: Te especifico más el error me salta ahora cuando se ejecuta esta línea ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
Dentro del for de las direcciones

Comment: @Ram: En efecto, creo entender el porqué del error a pesar del cambio. Le agregué a mi respuesta para ver si te resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma:

```
        //Aquí se produce el error
        ctx.Entry(socio).State = EntityState.Modified;             


        foreach (SocioDireccion d in socio.Direcciones)
        {
            if (d.Id == 0)
                ctx.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
            else
                {
                    // Uliza el método Find de tú DbSet Direcciones (cro que se llama así)
                    var data = context.Direcciones.Find(d.Id);
                    var entry = context.Entry(data);
                    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                }
        }

        r = ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Es otra forma de realizar los cambios, y así debería de funcionarte correctamente.

Te dejo un método genérico AddOrUpdate, que puede serte de gran ayuda en estos casos:

```
public virtual int InsertOrUpdate<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params object[] keyValues)  where TEntity : class
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity), $"El parámetro {nameof(entity)} no puede ser null");
    if (keyValues == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyValues), $"El parámetro {nameof(keyValues)} no puede ser null");

    int resultado = 0;

    var context = new TuContexto(); //CreateContext();

    var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

    var data = dbSet.Find(keyValues);

    if (data == null)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        var entry = context.Entry(data);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    }

    resultado = TuContexto.SaveChanges();

    TuContexto.Dispose(); //DisposeContext();

    return resultado;
}
```

Dejo un poco la creación y la destrucción del contexto a gusto del consumidor, por si se quisiera insertar en el constructor del mismo o en el mismo método o por donde se quiera.

Comment: He re realizado lo que me dices y el problema haciéndolo así es que me hace una inserción de más en las direcciones. Es decir en el ejemplo que pongo la primera dirección que existía  debería de hacer un update  y la añade.

Comment: Si te ocurre eso, debugea y verifica la comprobación por ID, la que difere de inserción a actualización, y revisa bien porque entra en cada una. Pq ese error ya no es de forma de actualizar, es de regla de negocio. Cuando hacemso un Find(pK), buscamos por clave primaria, comprueba que no sea más de un campo o si existen o no los registros que quieres insertar/actualizar